# jQuery Object array notation

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I'm new to jQuery, and I'm having a little trouble understanding its array notation for objects. Reading the jQuery docs and [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445599/jquery-object-as-a-array-id0), it seems that you can refer to the nth item in an object returned by a selector by doing something like

```
$('.foo')[n];
```

Correct?
Should I be able to use jQuery manipulation/effects functions in tandem? Something like (this isn't working for me)

```
$('.foo')[0].hide();
```

I've also tried, to no avail:

```
var arr = $('.foo').get();
arr[0].hide();
```

Is there something wrong in my syntax? What's the best way to do what I'm trying to do here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `[0]` array notation and the [`.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/) both return a reference to a DOM element within the jQuery object, and you can't use jQuery methods on DOM elements.

Try the [`eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead, because it returns a new jQuery object:

```
$('.foo').eq(0).hide();
```

Note also that having used the array notation or `.get()` to get a reference to a DOM element means you *can* then get direct access to the DOM element's properties, e.g.:

```
var firstElId = $('.foo')[0].id;
```

...with a second note that `$('.foo')[0]` will be `undefined` and `$('.foo')[0].id` will give an error if there are no elements matching the `'.foo'` selector.

Answer (score 6):

When you reference a jQuery object as an array you get a DOM element back. You'll need to convert it back to a jQuery object to use methods like .hide()

```
var bar = $('.foo')[n];
var $bar = $(bar);

$bar.hide();
```

Or just use jQuery's eq() method:

```
var bar = $('.foo').eq(n);
bar.hide();
```

Comment: The first example works, but it's a pretty heavy way to do it.  Better to simply use `.eq()` as in the second example.