# get the value from a td tag using jquery and rest

Tags: jquery, rest

i have this elemnt from the array,

`<td>​85%​</td>​`

how do i get the value of `85%` from it? I thought `.val()` or `.text()` might work. But do not understand why not. Can someone explain how to get the value and where my understanding is flawed.

this is my console view.

```
row
<tr>​<td>​DeviceName1​</td>​<td>​85%​</td>​<td>​87%​</td>​<td>​75%​</td>​<td>​63%​</td>​</tr>​
_.rest($(row).children())
[<td>​85%​</td>​, <td>​87%​</td>​, <td>​75%​</td>​, <td>​63%​</td>​]
_.rest($(row).children())[0]
<td>​85%​</td>​
_.rest($(row).children())[0].val()
Uncaught TypeError: _.rest(...)[0].val is not a function(…)
```

Comment: Not sure about the REST, but when you do call to 'first array member', you don't have jQuery object anymore - you can then apply vanillaJS functions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445599/jquery-object-as-a-array-id0 p.s. val() will not work, it is property of input types, text() should work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the first element in the array with `[0]`, it is no longer a JQuery object so it won't respond to `text()` or any other JQuery function.

You should directly call `.text()` on the JQuery object, so if you want to get text of each child:

```
$.each($(row).children(), function(index, value) {
  console.log($(value).text());
});
```

or if you want to get text of first child:

```
$(row).children().first().text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead use .html(), it will pick whatever there in td. generally input tags have value attributes, tr/td are part of tabular structure.

Comment: does not work `_.rest($(row).children())[0].html()
VM398:1 Uncaught TypeError: _.rest(...)[0].html is not a function(…)`

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to get the value of some n-th table cell in a given row, right?

Try this (you do not need `_.rest`):

```
$("td", row).eq(1).text()
```

This also works with a real document, see http://fiddle.jshell.net/067x52fq/.

The `[0].val is not a function` error is due to the fact that you get a DOM element with `[0]` and therefore cannot use any jQuery methods on it.