# jQuery click function is not attaching click event to anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

**HTML**

Inside `<div id='foo-bar-baz'>`
I have a series of image links with unique ids as below

```
<a href=''><img id='12341234' class='foo-bar-thumbnail-image' src='/path/to/image.jpg'></a>
<a href=''><img id='56785678' class='foo-bar-thumbnail-image' src='/path/to/image.jpg'></a>
```

**Javascript / JQuery**

The above div is created by a `$.get()` to a webservice which returns a chunk of HTML in variable `response`. On success, the `$.get()` calls the below function:

```
var thumbnailsDiv = function (response) 
    {
        var json = $.parseJSON(response);
        $('#foo-bar-baz').html(json.html);
        alert("Setting click functions on thumbnails");
        $('.foo-bar-thumbnail-image').unbind().click(function () {
            alert("I am thumbnail " + $(this).id);
        }, false);
    };
```

As you can see above, I'm trying to bind a click function to each of the image links. However this is not working (with or without the `unbind()`).

After the above code has run, if I inspect the image links in the Dev Tools, I can see that there are two click event attached already to the thumbnails. Neither of these is my function above. The paths for both of them are from other applications libraries embedded on the page: one is labelled 'jQuery' and the other is labelled 'Bubbling' and 'DOM2'. I'm guessing that it is these attached events that mean I can't add my event above, but I don't know enough about jQuery or javascript to know if this is true (I am a server-side developer normally, I don't know front-end stuff at all.)

Any suggestions as to how I get an on-click event working for these elements would be much appreciated, so that I can replace the demo code above with the code I need to run.

Comment: Shouldn't the '.' in your alert be a '+'? You are trying to concatenate aren't you?

Comment: Doh! Yes you're right - told you I was a dumbass server-side developer! That's PHP syntax. However if I fix that concatenation (which I'll do in the posting as well), and reload the code, I get the same problem. Also, why wasn't JS warning me that I had bad syntax? Shouldn't that have given me a warning in the Console or something? Anyway, thanks for helping - good catch.

Comment: You should be using `$(document).on('click','.foo-bar-thumbnail-image',function() ...` instead of `$.click(function()...` since the event handler is on rendered elements.

Comment: Do want the links to never catch a click event?

Comment: Try replacing the click function with this. $('.foo-bar-thumbnail-image').click(function () {
            alert("I am thumbnail " + $(this)[0].id);
        });

Comment: @MichaelCoker - thanks you solved my issue. If you want to post an answer I'll accept your solution, since you just pipped DanNagle to this. if you could also explain what you mean by 'since the event handler is on rendered elements' (or post a link to an explanation) that would be great too.

Comment: @Almond your note about dereferencing the $(this) variable also helped me out a lot. Why do I need $this[0] ? I have much to learn about jQuery.

Comment: $(this) is the jQuery object. $(this)[0] is the DOM element that the jQuery object encapsulates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445599/jquery-object-as-a-array-id0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `$(document).on('click','.foo-bar-thumbnail-image',function() ...` instead of `$.click(function()...` since the event handler is on elements that were rendered on the page via JS. That's a "delegated" event handler - you can read more about that here https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 3):

You just need to bind the `click` event to the parent element which already exists on the page.

```
$('#foo-bar-baz').on('click', '.foo-bar-thumbnail-image', function(){
  // what you want to happen when click 
  // occurs on elements that match '.foo-bar-thumbnail-image'
  // within '#foo-bar-baz'
  alert("I am thumbnail " + $(this).id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this @DanNagle however Michael Coker just beat you to it in the above comments. Much appreciated though.